# Php loop through an array

Tags: php

I have this array . I would like to archive the following and display each package name and the due date

```
   1.CLASSIC ASIA PLUS (2015-10-25)
   2.NEW SMART (2017-10-18)
```

Here is the array

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [subid] => 618341
            [currentpackage] => CLASSIC ASIA PLUS
            [lastpackage] => CLASSIC ASIA PLUS
            [duedate] => 2017-10-25
            [dueamount] => 54499
            [balance] => 443034
            [subclient] => ZukuSatUg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [subid] => 618341
            [currentpackage] => NEW SMART
            [lastpackage] => NEW SMART
            [duedate] => 2017-10-18
            [dueamount] => 399
            [balance] => 1
            [subclient] => ZukuSatKe
        )

)
```

This is what I have tried so far

```
 foreach ($package as $key => $val) {
        return $package[$key]['currentpackage']." [". $package[$key]['duedate']."]";
    }
```

The results am getting is this

```
CLASSIC ASIA PLUS [2017-10-25]
```

Only for the 1st one.

Comment: Have you tried anything or just wait when someone will give you code?

Comment: Not even a code sample?

Comment: Have you tried anything? For start you can read about [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and how to [access array elements using the square brackets syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing). You can then read about [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and don't skip the examples provided in the documentation. They are the best answer you can get.

Answer (score 0):

I found out solutions

```
  $list = null;
    foreach ($package as $key => $val) {
        $list.= $package[$key]['currentpackage']." [". $package[$key]['duedate']."] \n";
    }

    return $list;
```

out put is

```
CLASSIC ASIA PLUS [2017-10-25] 
NEW SMART [2017-10-18]
```